# How to implement on click listener on Grid Layout with Image View and Text View?

Tags: android, android-layout, android-intent

I want to use Grid Layout (not grid view) and in each cell i want image view and below it a  text view . i want to implement click listener on each cell of grid layout.Please someone tell me how to do this?

Comment: What have you tried so far? Can you provide any code you are having problems with?

Comment: check out my answer here it is exactly what you want and vote a answer if it is helpful  http://stackoverflow.com/a/31877898/2826147.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Supposing, that your cell layout's top most wrapper is RelativeLayout, here is the code, that might work:

```
GridLayout grid = (GridLayout) findViewById(R.id.your_layout_id);
int childCount = grid.getChildCount();

for (int i= 0; i < childCount; i++){
    RelativeLayout container = (RelativeLayout) grid.getChildAt(i);
    container.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener(){
        public void onClick(View view){
            // your click code here
        }
    });
}
```

Comment: I am using linear Layout not relative layout

Comment: So what? 
Just change RelativeLayout to LinearLayout in my code.
Thats all.
RelativeLayout was used just for example.

Comment: I'm glad it did.
Please, vote the answer up as accepted. Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

I believe then it would be better to use CardView with grid layout, and within CardView you can put image and text and you can directly set  onClickListener.
e.g.

```
cardApplication.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
                @Override
                public void onClick(View v) {
                    Intent intent=new Intent(MainActivity.this,ApplicationList.class);
                    startActivity(intent);
                }
            });
```

Where cardApplication is the name of my `CardView` within the grid layout.

This is what the xml of my `CardView` looks like:

```xml
<android.support.v7.widget.CardView
                        android:layout_width="0dp"
                        android:layout_height="0dp"
                        android:layout_columnWeight="1"
                        android:layout_rowWeight="1"
                        android:layout_marginBottom="16dp"
                        android:layout_marginLeft="16dp"
                        android:layout_marginRight="16dp"
                        app:cardElevation="8dp"
                        app:cardCornerRadius="8dp"
                        android:id="@+id/cardApplication"
                        android:clickable="true"
                        >
                        <LinearLayout
                            android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal|center_vertical"
                            android:layout_margin="16dp"
                            android:orientation="vertical"
                            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                            android:layout_height="wrap_content">
    
                            <ImageView
                                android:src="@drawable/ic_apps"
                                android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal"
                                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                                android:layout_height="wrap_content" />
                            <TextView
                                android:text="Applications"
                                android:textAlignment="center"
                                android:textColor="#000000"
                                android:textStyle="bold"
                                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                                android:layout_height="wrap_content" />
    
                        </LinearLayout>
```

Answer (score 0):

```
gl=(GridLayout) findViewById(R.id.gl);


    int childCount = gl.getChildCount();

    for(int i=0;i<childCount;i++){


       LinearLayout l = (LinearLayout) gl.getChildAt(i);
        l.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener(){
            public void onClick(View view){




                    Intent i=new      Intent(MainActivity.this,SecondActivity.class);
                    startActivity(i);


            }

        });
```

}

Comment: have you visited the link i have posted above ?

Answer (score 0):

Implementing `Clicklistener` on `childview` of Layout.
e.g. on `Imagebutton.setClicklistener(this)` and you can react on each cell
in Layout

you also can extend your own brickclass from View() class extends ImageButton

and then build your own methods member variales direct in Object

hope this helps
patrick wertal