# how to make a constant activity with many variable images, data..... : android studio

Tags: java, android, image, variables, android-activity

i create a (table) list of names, and images of those names in drawable, and each image i create an activity   so when i click the name it show the image in new activity .
(100 names means 100 activities)
the question is:
how to make one constant activity instead of many activities having image as variable?
(100 names need main activity and constant activity)

I watch many tutorials but didn't find the answer

Comment: I think you don't need to create 100 activities, you have 1 table, you pass this item clicked to a new activity, then this activity show it. I mean 1 activity that you pass an element you clicked

Comment: i know that every image must have a activity to  define and to show in the screen after I clicked the name I'm a beginner and i didn't know how to write the code to customize in one activity

Comment: Check this out https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31868468/how-do-i-open-an-image-by-clicking-on-a-listview-in-android